# Why use Function.prototype.bind instead of Function.prototype.call?

Tags: javascript

```
myFunction.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2 ...)
```

My understanding is that when I use `call` method and provide a `thisArg` the `this` value in the function is set to object I pass in.

```
myFunction.bind(thisArg, arg1, arg2 ...)
```

And the `bind` method on the other hand returns a new function with the context of `this` of the new function set to the object I pass in.

But what I don't understand is why use `bind` instead of a `call`. If all I want to do is change the context of `this`, `call` seems sufficient to me. Then why use bind when it breaks in browsers IE8 and below.

So, when does using `bind` become a better case compared to `call`?

Comment: When you want to pass the bound function to something else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> When does using `bind` become a better case compared to `call`?

Callbacks.

If you need to make sure that a function is called in the context of a particular object, but have no controll of how the function is called (such as when you pass a function as a parameter to a callback), you'd use `bind`.

```
var f,
    example;
f = new Foo();
example = document.getElementById('example');

//`f.bar` is called in the context of `f`
f.bar();

//`f.bar` will be called in the context of `example`
example.addEventListener('click', f.bar); 

//`f.bar` will be called in the context of `f`
example.addEventListener('click', f.bar.bind(f));
```

Comment: Was very nooby of me, but creating this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ6aS/9/) based on your example helped me clear the idea. Thanks!!